# Adding a Customer Review page in an existing word press theme

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a webpage in Wordpress. My theme doesn't have a customer review page. So i want to manually add a page to display customer reviews. It should work like, the customer can write a review by giving his name and mail and then the actul review, after that he can submit it. Once he submitted then the review has to be displayed in the Review page. I need some help or any suggesting for any related plugins where i can do this.

Comment: Its not very clear what is the issue here. Just make 1 new page, call it Review and allow comments for authenticated users, you can have 1 custom template for this page, copy->paste the comments template inside and style it however you want in order the "Reviews" to look different from the regular comments.

Comment: I need to make form inside the theme and let the customer to review the product. Once he submitted the review the i need to display it straight away in my page

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Custom Post type** for it. create custom post type with name "customer review". you can create it using https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/ plugin.

After that you need to create archive-your custom posttype slug (ex. archive-customer_review.php) page and fetch custom posttype data like below:

```
<?php 

$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'services',
    'areas'    => 'painting',
    'order'    => 'ASC'
    );              

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
?>
```